# How to add trailing slashes to links in my pages from .htaccess in addition to the redirects I've implemented?

Tags: htaccess, url, canonical-url, trailing-slash

I've recently appended the trailing slash at the end of the URL by using this *.htaccess* code:

```
#add trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

When I copy the URL from any element from the page, like this for example, it doesn't show trailing slash in the end. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> but when I copy the url from any element from the page like this for example, It doesn't show Trailing slash in the end. Why?

The `.htaccess` directive you posted doesn't change your HTML source, it simply redirects HTTP requests sent to your server.

> how to add trailing slash everywhere, not just in the main url search bar

You need to edit the HTML source / generation.

(You appear to have since modified the HTML source so that the links do now include the trailing slash?)

Comment: where can i get a http access code for the http source?

Comment: no,  i had a plugin called permalink manager having an option to add the permalink.  But i do want to add it via http access code.

Comment: "where can i get a http access code for the http source?" - I assume by "http access", you are referring to `.htaccess`. You can't - it doesn't work like that. You can't change the HTML source using `.htaccess`.

Comment: "But i do want to add it via http access code." - What makes you think you "want" to do that? You should add the trailing slash using your plugin (or CMS) etc.

Comment: I don't have any problem with the trailing slash now.. I think, I'll use plugin. thanks for the help